# Finding Specific Rows in SQL which must Includes Value From ColumnB

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to below table. I want to select all ColumnA Values which has the Value "X" for ColumnB but also other possible ColumnB values.

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| One | X |
| One | Y |
| Two | Y |
| Two | Z |
| Three | X |
| Three | Z |

So basically the query should result like this. Can you help me to achieve this?

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| One | X |
| One | Y |
| Three | X |
| Three | Z |

Answer (score 0):

One solution: once you know what Table1 values you want you can select them. So resolve that in a subquery. We'll alias the original table as `X` and the subquery as `Y`:

```
select X.* 
from Table1 X
inner join
(
    select 
        ColumnA
    from 
        Table1 
    Where 
        ColumnB = 'X'
) Y
on X.ColumnA = Y.ColumnA
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use min() over a window:

```
select columnA, columnB 
from (
    select *, min(columnb) over(partition by columna) mb
    from t
)t
where mb = 'X';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a subquery would be the simplest way.
Step 1 - find all the columnA values where columnB = 'x'

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
FROM table_name
WHERE ColumnB = 'x'
```

step 2 - select all the records where the value in ColumnA is in this list

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE ColumnA in (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
                  FROM table_name
                  WHERE ColumnB = 'x')
```